# Dealing with and addressiung the "XML flaws" security issue

Tags: xml

I read [this story today on El Reg](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/08/06/xml_flaws/) and I'm wondering if anyone in our community has identified issues within their own projects that relate to this and if so, what are those issues, how critical are they, and more importantly, what is being done to mitigate them?

A more detailed source for information surrounding this story can be [found here](http://www.codenomicon.com/labs/xml/) (thanks to [Andrew Hare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34211/andrew-hare) for this).

Comment: The article you posted is a bit thin on the details - this article http://www.codenomicon.com/labs/xml/ has a bit more info.

Comment: **@Andrew:** Thanks. I hadn't had chance to look for other sources yet. That's great.

Comment: If I understand the Codenomicon report correctly, "XML flaws" means that perversely crafted XML breaks most parsers causing "a denial-of-service situation, corruption of data, or maybe even a situation where hostile code can be executed on the vulnerable host."

Comment: Not a problem!  What a weird issue - I had never heard of it until today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a bit early to tell. [CERT-FI has some details](http://www.cert.fi/en/reports/2009/vulnerability2009085.html) on the affected libraries, and Sun's page references a [CVE entry](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2009-2625) that is still under review. No one seems to have developed an exploit for the vulnerability; it looks like it is (so far) limited to an XML denial of service attack, and they are not new.

On the other hand, it looks like it affects all versions of Java, Apache Xerces, and libexpat. That's pretty widespread.